# how to fix my images into different screen resolutions in android

Tags: android, view

In my application, I have 12 images in a view. After I designing view, When I run the application only 9 images are appearing remaining 3 are out of view. How can I rectify those problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make images 9 patch, use dpi for fixed sizes if needed, have different resolution for images (mdpi,hdpi etc..)

Comment: where should i give size of the image in dpis

Comment: in your xml use layout_width="40dp" and layout_height="40dp" instead of wrap_content which you most likely are using now.

Answer (score 0):

use 9 patch image , also to define width and height use dpi
see http://codetrips.blogspot.in/2010/12/android-draw-9-patch-seems-broken-too.html
for 9 patch